# Query to insert a second table into the first table if table1.id = table2.table1_id

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two tables.

```
*brands b*
id, name, img

*models m*
id, name, img, brand_1
```

I would like to get the following output:

**Expected result / output**

```
b.id, 
b.name, 
b.img, 
models = m.id, m.name, m.img (where b.id = m.brand_id);
```

Do I have to do two steps for this?

1. give me all the brands
2. iterate brands and give me all models that are `m.brand_id = b.id`.

I hope you understand what I mean. In the PHP Laravel Framework you can get one to many relationships as a collection. Can I solve this with a query? And is my approach the right one at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can laravel   always let you show the raw query that the quera builder constructs.

but basically you are searching for an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT
  b.id, 
  b.name, 
  b.img, 
  m.id as models
  , m.name
  , m.img 
FROM models  m INNER JOIN brands ON b.id = m.brand_id;
```